# Restore Default Permissions in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, permissions

I recently changed the owner of Windows 8.1 "Windows" folder (`C:\Windows`) to me (I am the administrator so I changed the owner to 
`ComputerName\Administrators` and removed privileges of the regular users.

I was trying to limit one of the user's access then this led to a 
total disaster -- almost all of the installed applications won't work and system default applications won't work.

Is there is any way to undo this and restore defaults ?

Comment: Not a duplicate, resetting permissions for Windows files is different. user3090933 see this page....https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d09a393b-68df-43de-9f31-735f83242497/quick-way-to-reset-all-security-permissions-to-default-windows-7?forum=w7itprosecurity

Comment: @Moab - My first comment suggest that command.  Go Figure...I was right the first time.

Comment: First of all this question is not a duplicate as the solutions mentioned in the other question failed for me also I would like to know the way to reset permissions of "Program Files" .